# when i scroll down load div in php page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Am creating a PHP page for E-com. I have 100 products in database, but am showing only 12 products in page using following code

**product.php**

```
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("select * from products limit 12");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql))
{
$p_img = $row['product_image'];
$p_name = $row['product_name'];
$p_desc = $row['product_desc'];
$p_price = $row['price'];
?>
<div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3 ">
  <div class="thumbnail">
     <img src="images/product/<?php echo $p_img; ?>" alt="products"  />
     <div class="caption">
     <h4><?php echo $p_name;?></h4>
     <p><?php echo $p_desc;?></p>
     <p style="font-size:17px;"><b><i class="fa fa-inr"></i> <?php echo $p_price;?></p>
     <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button">Button</a> 
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" role="button">Button</a></p>
   </div>
</div><!--thumbnail end-->
```

My question is when i scroll the muose add more 8 products in same page. How can i add that ?.

Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Write an ajax function after page is scrolled to 70% example:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.7) {
   callajaxhere();
}

function callajaxhere(){
   // ajax call to load products
}
```

Comment: what is callajaxhere ? is this function name

Answer (score 0):

When you're page is scrolled for example the window is scrolled for 70%.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= ($(document).height() - $(window).height())*0.7){
     $.ajax({url: "phpfile.php", success: function(result){
        $("body").html(result);
     }});
}
```

In you're php file you request too, you print the next 8. This will be in the variable `result`. So `results` contains the next 8, add this with Jquery or javascript  too you're page. Here is documentation of [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you want to do some more with it.